# Trying to update table with values from second table MySQL results in unending "running query"

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to replace null values in one table with values from a second table, based on matches from other columns in both tables. While the code does not result in error, it does not stop running, producing an unending "running query" signal. code is here
    UPDATE pl_building b
    INNER JOIN pl_grt t
    ON b.INST = t.inst 
    SET b.Utuition=t.tuition
    WHERE b.UtUITION = 0;

Answer (score 0):

You should not update on join tables.

I am not sure what field you want to update, but your SQL should look like this:

```
UPDATE pl_building b 
SET b.Utuition= (select t.tuition from  pl_grt t ON b.INST = t.inst) 
WHERE b.UtUITION = 0;
```

Make sure :

1) You have an index on `t.inst` table column and maybe also on `b.UtUITION`

2) Relationship between `b.INST = t.inst` is unique. Never returns more than 1 row.